# Collapse Empty Columns Around Date Column in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple columns for each header. I would like to collapse them into one column. For some reason the user spread what was supposed to go into one column across five.
Given this:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--+
|            |           |    DOB    |           |           |  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--+
|            |           | 1/7/1980  |           |           |  |
|            |           |           |           | 1/30/1947 |  |
|            |           |           | 3/12/1948 |           |  |
|            |           | 1/26/1941 |           |           |  |
|            | 6/26/1951 |           |           |           |  |
| 12/29/1974 |           |           |           |           |  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--+
```

I want this:

```
DOB
1/7/1980
1/30/1947
3/12/1948
1/26/1941
6/26/1951
12/29/1974
```

I tried this, but it creates turn of century dates for each of the blank columns. 
TEXT(A1,"m/d/yyyy")&TEXT(B1,"m/d/yyyy") . . .

How can I avoid that? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Of course if you then need to delete the empty columns using vba, that is a completely separate issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Excel formulas can add dates, assuming your other 4 cells in the row are truly blank, you could just write this formula:

```
=Sum(B1:B5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this pretty cool custom function to easily combine an entire range via [Excel VBA function to concatenate non-empty cells with a user defined seperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929028/excel-vba-function-to-concatenate-non-empty-cells-with-a-user-defined-seperator):

```
=ConcatenateRange(B1:B5,"")
```

Using the custom function:

```
Function ConcatenateRange(ByVal cell_range As Range, _
                    Optional ByVal seperator As String) As String

Dim cell As Range
Dim newString As String
Dim cellArray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

cellArray = cell_range.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(cellArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(cellArray, 2)
        If Len(cellArray(i, j)) <> 0 Then
            newString = newString & (seperator & cellArray(i, j))
        End If
    Next
Next

If Len(newString) <> 0 Then
    newString = Right$(newString, (Len(newString) - Len(seperator)))
End If

ConcatenateRange = newString

End Function
```